# Стоит ли пользоваться такой аннотацией @SuppressLint, по подсказке Андроид Студио?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Или избегать**, по возможности ?! Т.е., искать решения такие, чтобы в коде не появлялись авто-вставки (над методами) типа @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") и т.п.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы понимаете о чем вас предупреждают, и осознанно принимаете решение, что в данной ситуации вам нужно сделать именно так, как вы сделали, то ставьте аннотацию подавления.

Если в принципе согласны, что отмеченный код "пахнет", но времени и желания прямо сейчас править нет, то оставьте все как есть. Это предупреждение будет мозолить глаза и, когда нибудь, вы не вытерпите и поправите.

Надо понимать, что, как и любой инструмент статического анализа, Lint может выдавать ложно-положительные срабатывания (хоть и редко). Также помните, что большАя часть предупреждений касается Best Practics. Они совсем не обязательны для применения, но в большинстве случаев лучше их придерживаться.

Пример ложно-положительного срабатывания, когда Lint сообщает об "ошибке", которой на самом деле нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ещё в евентбасе сабскрабы not used )

Comment: @Flippy да много их, тут просто наглядно очень.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, как вы используете LINT. Более того вы можеет настроить IDE и убирать орпеделенные проверки у LINTа, приоритет которых считаете низким и такие там есть, но....

**Я считаю что такие аннотации должны сводится к минимуму, а если они используются то должны быть обоснованы**. Некоторые из них приведут просто к крашу, например @SuppressLint («NewApi») это по сути игнор minSdk и это очень плохо. А когда вы ставите такую аннотацию вы закрываете на это глаза и ещё inspection нормально не сделать. У вас ситуация очень схожа.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
```

Означачет, что есть методы которые принимают факическиое RGB, и вы их там хардкодите и это очень плохо со стороны разработки.

1.Такой код может привести к падению, если в сете указаны неверные параметры.

2.Такой код становится не адаптивным к изменениям, если у вас есть 3+ места, вам придется править ручками и сразу смотрите пункт 1, возможность ошибки, возможность падения.

3.Такой код не поддается изменениям  в стилях в приложения. Что иногда критично.

> Решение:
>   Перед тем как сетить цвет. Вам нужно явно забрать из ресурсов.

```
getResources (). getColor (resID)
```